# Cannot display result set in Win Form DatagridView

Tags: datagridview, webforms

I cannot display the results sets from my query in the datagridview.  When I step through the code, I can see the data in the data adapter table and the binding source, but it will not display in the grid?  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ("my conn string");

    //open
    conn.Open();

    ////pass the conn to command object
    string query = "select  * from main (nolock) where platter = 'first' and uk_5 in (" + List + ")";

    //create adapter to get data    
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

    // Get data set instance
    DataSet dTable = new DataSet();

    // Fill data set
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

    //binding source to the data set
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = dTable;

    //displaying in datagridview
    DataGridView dgView = new DataGridView();
    dgView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dgView.DataSource = bSource;

    //close
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the DataGridView that you're programmatically creating to any form, so it will not be displayed on your form .  Add this code after you bind your BindingSource to your DataGridView:

```
Controls.Add(dgView);
```

Note that a DataGridView added to a form in this manner will be positioned and sized using defaults you probably don't want.

You can either create the DataGridView in the form designer or set these values programmatically: (example: dgView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100); )

Comment: I tried doing everyting in the designer, but my string can only handle one 'number'.  In the properties in the query builder/Query Designer/Query Parameter List/@mystring (nvarchar(50)).  I cannot change the type.  I tried to cast and convert it, but it doesn't work in the designer.  my string for example will be 1,2,3.  the query will only handle one value, it won't see 1,2,3 as the one string (bug maybe vs2010).  So I'm trying to do it just by coding it.  My sql In statement works fine, but even after adding your line (thanks!) it still didn't work.